# By clicking increment button web page is not updating with the incremented value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, shopping-cart

### component.ts

```js
  decrement(index: number) {
    this.incrementgetdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems'));
    if (this.incrementgetdata !== null) {
      this.incrementgetdata[index].quantity -= 1;
      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(this.incrementgetdata));
    }
  }
  
  increment(index: number) {
    this.incrementgetdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems'));
    if (this.incrementgetdata !== null) {
      this.incrementgetdata[index].quantity += 1;
      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(this.incrementgetdata));
      window.location.reload(true);
    }

  }
  getDetails() {
    this.getselectedproducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems'));
    console.log(this.getselectedproducts);
  }
  getDetails();
```

```html
componen.html
------------
 <div class="border-bottom mb-3 d-inline-block" *ngFor="let products of getselectedproducts; let i = index">
          <div class="col-md-12" >
            <div class="col-md-6  d-inline-block">
              <img class="w-75" [src]="products.image">
              <div>
                <div class="btn-group mt-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="d-inline-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="decrement(i)">-</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-inline-flex">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" [value]="products.quantity"
                      [(ngModel)]="products.quantity">
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-inline-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="increment(i)">+</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6  d-inline-block">
              <div>
                <h3>{{products.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{products.cost | currency: 'INR'}}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeproduct(products)">Remove from Cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```js
increment(index: number) {
    this.incrementgetdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems'));
    if (this.incrementgetdata !== null) {
      this.incrementgetdata[index].quantity += 1;
      this.editedquantity = this.getselectedproducts[index].quantity;
      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(this.incrementgetdata));
      console.log('edited quantity', this.editedquantity);
      window.location.reload(true);
    }

  }
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="increment(i)">+</button>
                  </div>
```

Iam new to angular. I need this solution for my project. its very important for me. when ever i click on increment button it is not updated, it is updated when page reload, so i kept window.location.reload(true); can anyone tell me, without window.location.reload(true);

(Increase button for product quantity in cart)

Exmp.

```js
 increment(index: number) {
 let incrementgetdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems'));
    if (incrementgetdata !== null) {
      incrementgetdata[index].quantity += 1;
      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(incrementgetdata));
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do yo display it into the .html file ?

Comment: Can you please check, code is updated

Comment: still where are you displaying/binding increment data, provide that snippet

Comment: Okay but I meant how do you display the counter. Now, what 's the output of `console.log('edited quantity', this.editedquantity);` ?

Comment: ignore these    this.editedquantity = this.getselectedproducts[index].quantity 
 console.log('edited quantity', this.editedquantity);

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "It's not updated". You don't have any label in .html that refer to a counter. So what do you expect to be updated ?

Comment: I have updated the comment, by adding app.component.ts and app.component.html

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz demo if possible or the code that you have tried with expected and current output!

Comment: How to i reload the div with out reload the page